# Trouble installing tf-object-detection using pip

Tags: python, tensorflow

`pip install tf-object-detection` gives me this error:

```
ERROR: Cannot install tf-object-detection==0.0.1, tf-object-detection==0.0.2, tf-object-detection==0.0.2.1, tf-object-detection==0.0.2.3, tf-object-detection==0.0.2.4, tf-object-detection==0.0.2.5, tf-object-detection==0.0.2.6, tf-object-detection==0.0.2.7 and tf-object-detection==0.0.3 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    tf-object-detection 0.0.3 depends on tensorflow-gpu<2.0
    tf-object-detection 0.0.2.7 depends on tensorflow-gpu<2.0
    tf-object-detection 0.0.2.6 depends on tensorflow-gpu<2.0
    tf-object-detection 0.0.2.5 depends on tensorflow-gpu<2.0
    tf-object-detection 0.0.2.4 depends on tensorflow-gpu<2.0
    tf-object-detection 0.0.2.3 depends on tensorflow-gpu<2.0
    tf-object-detection 0.0.2.1 depends on tensorflow-gpu<2.0
    tf-object-detection 0.0.2 depends on tensorflow-gpu<2.0
    tf-object-detection 0.0.1 depends on tensorflow-gpu<2.0

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies
```

Not sure how to loosen range of package versions, as it seems like I would have to edit the `setup.py` associated with package. I haven't been able to find people with similar questions.

Any advice?

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> python --version
Python 3.9.5
PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Comment: Simple, install TensorFlow 1.x

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @Dr. Snoopy Install Tensorflow 1.x.
tf-object-detection `>0.0.1 , <0.0.3` requires `Tensorflow-gpu== 1.x`.

Check the Object Detection API with TensorFlow 2 [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2.md).